# R install nlopt dependency via proxy

Tags: r, proxy, installation, http-proxy

I'm trying to install nloptr (or caret) after having set my http_proxy via Sys.setenv(http_proxy="my_proxy"). I'm running on a Linux box, trying to install a personal library (because I don't have write access to the global dist).

It works until it gets to:

```
configure: Need to download and build NLopt
trying URL 'http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz'
...
Execution halted.
```

This error is coming from line 3301 in nloptr's configure script:

```
## Download NLopt source code
## curl -O http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-${NLOPT_VERSION}.tar.gz
$("${R_HOME}/bin/Rscript" --vanilla -e "download.file(url='${NLOPT_URL}', destfile='${NLOPT_TGZ}')")
```

This can be fixed by removing the `--vanilla` from the configure script, then re-running. But, that doesn't make it easy for me to tell my colleagues how to accomplish installing this library for themselves.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can simply download the source and install

```
wget http://ab-initio.mit.edu/nlopt/nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz
R CMD INSTALL nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz
```

*Edit*

or much better, somthing like this might work for the newest version:

```
sudo R -e \"install.packages('nlopt',repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')\"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this didn't work because nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz is not an R library.

    `R CMD INSTALL nlopt-2.4.2.tar.gz
    Error in untar2(tarfile, files, list, exdir, restore_times) :                                                                     
    unsupported entry type ‘’`